# Seeing imports in only show the selected Java element mode

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I am using eclipse 4.3.1 and like using it with the option " only show the selected Java element mode " turned on as it focuses you on the current issue.

How do I see the imports to the package. I can find the package command using the Outline view and the class and members using Outline or Members view but I can't see a way to see or edit the imports. I think earlier versions showed the imports as a section in the Outline view but does not seem to be there for my eclipse.

Comment: I don't know the reason for editing imports. You can directly use any classes in your build path and when compiler crys for unresolved symbol use quick fix to import it.

Comment: I wanted to see the imports in another file + quick import doesn't seem to always work